# Oracle 11g Forms Javascript Event Calls - How to Set the Configuration ID Variable

Tags: javascript, forms, oracle11g

I'm trying to integrate Oracle Forms with Javascript and am using this documentation from Oracle as a guide:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10240/javascript.htm

I'm having trouble with section 6.2 where it says:

"document.forms_applet.raiseEvent(event_name, payload);

The assumption here is that you have set the ID configuration variable to forms_applet."

I don't know how to set the ID configuration variable. Does anyone know how to do this? Google didn't seem to be very much help and the Oracle doco was too vague for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where to set the ID of the form. It's in the applet definition inside the  tag.

```
<OBJECT classid="cldis:DAEID"
        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab#version=1,6,0,12"
        WIDTH="1000"
        HEIGHT="800"
        HSPACE="0"
        VSPACE="0"
        ID="forms_applet">
```

Then after changing the ID I can do things in my javascript like:

```
document.forms_applet.raiseEvent("myEvent", "My string for the event");
```